# Proper way to access nested foreignkey objects?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have models with hierarchical relationships:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Class(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class Student(models.Model):
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
```

And I'd like to retrieve every `Student` objects related to certain `School`.
I usually did it like below:

```
the_school = School.objects.get(name='Springfield Elementary School')
students = Student.objects.filter(class__school=the_school)
```

But this method needs two models to look up (`School` and `Student`) which seems somewhat unnecessary... For me.
So I tried to make a single line query, using Django's built in related manager:

```
students = School.objects.get(name='...').class_set.student_set.all()
# or 
students = School.objects.get(name='...').class_set.all().student_set.all()
```

...which did not work.

How can I make a query referencing down from given `School` object?
Or is there any better solution?

Comment: As neverwalkaloner shows in his answer, the trick is to start from the class you want - that is, Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class__school__name` as filter argument:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(class__school__name='Springfield Elementary School''Springfield Elementary School')
```